# React/Redux: Need help render API Response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I am working on a recipe app. I'm using Yummly API I am getting a response however I am confused how to render the data I get back from the API because the response is a Object with an array of recipes. When I try to render the array I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {imageUrlsBySize, sourceDisplayName, ingredients, id, smallImageUrls, recipeName, totalTimeInSeconds, attributes, flavors, rating}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Link to an image of what the API response looks like:

[Object from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9JRT.png)
"Matches" is the part I want to render in my component

Action.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {LOOK_UP_RECIPE`enter code here`} from './types';

 const API_ID = '########';
 const API_KEY = '######';
 const ROOT_LOOK_UP_URL = `http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes? 
 _app_id=${API_ID}&_app_key=${API_KEY}`


export function lookuprecipesYummly(ingredients) {
 const yummlyurl =`${ROOT_LOOK_UP_URL}&q=${ingredients}`; 
 const request = Axios.get(yummlyurl);

return {
    type: LOOK_UP_RECIPE,
    payload: request
};
}
```

Reducer.js

```
import { LOOK_UP_RECIPE } from '../actions/types'
export default function(state = [], action) {
 console.log(action)
 switch (action.type){
    case LOOK_UP_RECIPE:
        return [ action.payload.data, ...state ];
 default:
    return state;
 }
}
```

Component:

```
    import _ from "lodash";
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class RecipeList extends Component {

 renderRecipe(recipeData) {
    return (
        <tr key={0}>
            <td key={1}>{recipeData.matches}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}

render() {

    return(
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr key={1}>
                    <th>Recipe</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {this.props.recipes.map(this.renderRecipe)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
}


function mapStateToProps({recipes}) {
   return {
       recipes
      }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipeList);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to render some JSX. Right now you're just returning an array of objects. React doesn't know what to do with that. Can you post what is inside one of the `recipeData.matches` object?

Comment: To just quickly spit out the data as a string, you can do `<td>{JSON.stringify(recipeData.matches)}</td>`.

Comment: Also, can you post what is inside `this.props.recipes`? I think your `.map` might be wrong.

Comment: Hey Chase DeAnda, I changed the the td to --> <td>{JSON.stringify(recipeData.matches)} and got a long string of what in the Matches array. So it's that information that I need to render

Comment: Right, your map should actually be at that level. Can you post what the data for `this.props.recipes` looks like?

Comment: I added an image of the data in recipes at the end of the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the data for each recipe inside some [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). Here is an example of how to populate a table row:

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class RecipeList extends Component {

    renderRecipe(recipe) {
        return (
            <tr key={recipe.id}>
                <td>{recipe.recipeName}</td>
                <td>{recipe.rating}</td>
                <td>{recipe.attributes.course[0]}</td>
                <td>{recipe.ingredients.join(', ')}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Recipe</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Course</th>
                        <th>Ingredients</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.recipes.matches.map(this.renderRecipe)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps({recipes}) {
    return { recipes }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipeList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help really appreciate it. But when I tried this I get the error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined    I don't understand why, I'm new to React

Comment: You need to add a check to make sure that `this.props.recipes.matches` is an array first. From the example data you posted, I assumed that it would always exist. You'll have to work out the kinks with your data, but you can use this approach for how to render an array of objects.